# How to count number of multiple matches in sinle line format of thousands files

Tags: grep

I have to count number of matches "@" in a folder with thousands of single lined files. I'm trying to use grep but no hope, any suggestion on using other programs like python or so?

This command give total number of hits in all files:

```
grep -rso @ *.tre | wc -l
```

5350

This spits only fist hit in each file:

```
grep -rosc @ *.tre

cluster517.tre:1
cluster547.tre:1
cluster558.tre:1
cluster559.tre:1
cluster562.tre:1
```

I want some thing like this:

```
cluster517.tre:36
cluster547.tre:37
cluster558.tre:23
cluster559.tre:40
cluster562.tre:12
```

where '@' appeared 36 times in the 'cluster517.tre' file or the results to be save in a txt file.

Comment: Your example works here. Which version of `grep` are you using?

Comment: In OSX: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Okay, I was testing with GNU grep 2.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it in bash if all the files are in one folder as your question states:

```
for F in *.tre ; do
    echo -n "$F:"
    cat "$F" | tr -d -C @ | wc -m | tr -d ' '
done > results.txt
```

I qualified it as working for only one directory because you also used grep's recursive (-r) flag in your code, which might imply that you want a recursive search.

This will save the results to a file named "results.txt".  If you want to view the results instead, just remove `> results.txt`.

Comment: @Ramon You're welcome.  If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow